# Sub Query Error, how to solve

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

When running the below query, I get an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I know what it means, but am unsure how to resolve it, I was thinking of creating a For Each Loop, that will compare the sites in my budget table and return the value based on the different sites.

Your input will be greatly appreciated.

```
Declare @FromDate DateTime
DEclare @ToDate DateTime
Declare @WACost Numeric (18,2)
Declare @WABill Numeric (18,2)
Declare @FBill Numeric (18, 2)
Declare @FCost Numeric (18,2)

Set @FromDate = '20160501'
Set @ToDate = '20160531'

Set @WACost = (
              Select
                    sum(dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + Sum((dbo.FleetData.OwnCost + dbo.FleetData.OpCost)
                    * dbo.DataInput.Hrs)
              From       dbo.DataInput INNER JOIN
                         dbo.HRData ON dbo.DataInput.HRId = dbo.HRData.HRId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetData ON dbo.FleetData.FleetId = dbo.DataInput.FleetId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.WorkCodes ON dbo.DataInput.WorkCodeId = dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID
             WHERE ProdDate >= @FromDate AND ProdDate <= @ToDate and dbo.workcodes.WorkCode = 101
              ) 

Set @WABill = (
              Select
                sum(dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + Sum((dbo.FleetData.OwnBill + dbo.FleetData.OpBill)
                * dbo.DataInput.Hrs)
              From dbo.Datainput Inner Join
                   dbo.FleetData ON dbo.FleetData.FleetId = dbo.DataInput.FleetId INNER JOIN
                   dbo.HRData ON dbo.DataInput.HRId = dbo.HRData.HRId INNER JOIN
                   dbo.WorkCodes ON dbo.DataInput.WorkCodeId = dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID

              WHERE ProdDate >= @FromDate AND ProdDate <= @ToDate and dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode = 101
              )

Set @FBill = (
             Select
                ((dbo.Budget.SalWage * (1 + dbo.Budget.SalWagePerc)) + dbo.budget.PG0 + 
                (dbo.budget.PG * (1 + PGPerc))) / (DAY(EOMONTH(@ToDate))) * Day(@ToDate)

             From dbo.budget 

             WHERE Period >= Month(@FromDate) and Period <= Month(@ToDate)
              )

Set @FCost = (
                Select (dbo.Budget.SalWage + dbo.budget.PG0 + dbo.budget.PG) / 
                (DAY(EOMONTH(@ToDate))) * Day(@ToDate)

                From dbo.budget 

                WHERE Period >= Month(@FromDate) and Period <= Month(@ToDate)
             )

SELECT     

             @WACost as WACostTotal, @WABill as WABillTotal, @FBill as FBillCalc, @FCost as FCostCalc,

              dbo.DataInput.DataInputID as DataInpID, dbo.DataInput.ProdDate as ProdDate, dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode as WCode, dbo.DataInput.Hrs as ProdHrs, dbo.DataInput.Loads as ProdLoads, 
              dbo.DataInput.Fuel as ProdFuel, dbo.FleetData.FleetNo as ProdFltNo, dbo.JobCodes.JobCode, 
              dbo.FleetType.EquipmentType as EqType, dbo.FleetModel.ModelName as Model, dbo.Sites.SiteName as ProdSiteName, 
              dbo.JobCodes.JobDetails as JCDet, dbo.JobCodes.BillMeth as BillM,
              dbo.FleetData.OwnCost as FltOwnCost, dbo.fleetdata.OpCost as FltOpCost, dbo.fleetdata.OwnBill as FltOwnBill,
              dbo.FleetData.OpBill as FltOpBill,

              (dbo.FleetModel.ModelSize * dbo.DataInput.Loads) as ProdBCM,
              dbo.HRData.EmpNo as HREmp, dbo.HRData.RatePH as EmpCost, dbo.HRData.RateBill as EmpBill, 
              dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs as ProdShHrs, dbo.FleetModel.ModelSize as MSize, 
              (dbo.DataInput.Fuel * dbo.JobCodes.FuelRate) as ProdFuelCost,
              dbo.budget.BudDate as BdgDate, dbo.Budget.RevBCM as BdgRevBCM, dbo.Budget.PricePerBCM as BdgBCMPrice,
              dbo.budget.BCMValue as BdgBCMVal, dbo.budget.SalWage as BdgSalWage, dbo.budget.Fuel as FuelBdg, 
              dbo.budget.PG0 as PGZero, dbo.budget.PG as PGCP,
              dbo.budget.siteId as BudgSite,

               --LAST DAY BCM
              IIF(dbo.DataInput.ProdDate = @ToDate, dbo.DataInput.Loads * dbo.FleetModel.ModelSize, 0) as LDBCM,

              --BILLING CALCS

              --PG Billing
              IIF(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.Budget.SalWage * (1 + dbo.Budget.SalWagePerc)) + dbo.budget.PG0 + 
              (dbo.budget.PG * (1 + PGPerc)),0) as PGBill,

              --FleetBill
              IIF(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as FleetBill,

              --LabourCost
              iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill),0) as LabourBill,  

              --Total Variable Bill
              iif(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + 
               (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as TotalVarBill,

               --WABill
               iif(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + 
               (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs) / 
               @WABill * @FBill +
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + 
               (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs), 0) as WABill,

              --COST CALCS

              --PG Cost

              IIF(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.Budget.SalWage + dbo.budget.PG0 + dbo.budget.PG),0) as PGCost,

              --FLEETCOST
              IIF(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as FleetCost,

              --LabourCost
              iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH),0) as LabourCost,

               --Total Variables Cost
               iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as TotalVarCost,

               --WAOnly
               iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs) / 
               @WACost * @FCost,0)
               as WACalc,

               --WA
               iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs) / 
               @WACost * @FCost +
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs) , 0) as WACost


FROM            dbo.DataInput INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetData ON dbo.FleetData.FleetId = dbo.DataInput.FleetId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetMake ON dbo.FleetData.FleetMakeId = dbo.FleetMake.FleetMakeId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetModel ON dbo.FleetData.FleetModelId = dbo.FleetModel.ModelId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetType ON dbo.FleetData.FleetTypeId = dbo.FleetType.FleetTypeId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.HRData ON dbo.DataInput.HRId = dbo.HRData.HRId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Sites ON dbo.DataInput.SiteId = dbo.Sites.SiteId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Budget ON dbo.Sites.SiteId = dbo.Budget.SiteId AND dbo.DataInput.Period = dbo.Budget.Period INNER JOIN
                         dbo.WorkCodes ON dbo.DataInput.WorkCodeId = dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.JobCodes ON dbo.DataInput.JobCodeId = dbo.JobCodes.JobCodeId

WHERE ProdDate >= @FromDate AND ProdDate <= @ToDate

Group By dbo.DataInput.DataInputID, dbo.DataInput.DataInputID, dbo.DataInput.ProdDate, dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode, dbo.DataInput.Hrs,
              dbo.DataInput.Loads, dbo.DataInput.Fuel, dbo.FleetData.FleetNo, dbo.JobCodes.JobCode, 
              dbo.FleetType.EquipmentType, dbo.FleetModel.ModelName, dbo.Sites.SiteName, 
              dbo.JobCodes.JobDetails, dbo.JobCodes.BillMeth, dbo.FleetData.OwnCost, dbo.fleetdata.OpCost, 
              dbo.fleetdata.OwnBill, dbo.FleetData.OpBill,dbo.HRData.EmpNo, dbo.HRData.RatePH, dbo.HRData.RateBill, 
              dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs, dbo.FleetModel.ModelSize, dbo.budget.BudDate, dbo.Budget.RevBCM, dbo.Budget.PricePerBCM,
              dbo.budget.BCMValue, dbo.budget.SalWage, dbo.budget.Fuel, dbo.budget.PG0, dbo.budget.PG,
              dbo.budget.siteId, dbo.jobcodes.FuelRate, dbo.datainput.workcodeid, dbo.budget.SalWagePerc, dbo.Budget.PGPerc, 
              dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID  

Order By dbo.DataInput.ProdDate
```

Comment: If you want to go with the same query, then make sure each sub query returns only one record. If it returns more than one you will face such error. You can user **TOP 1** in each sub query to avoid such error. For example **Set @FBill = (SELECT TOP 1**

Comment: It would really help if you could provide sample data.  Also include the output you would expect that sample to produce.  SO has a [guide on providing good examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here, which may help you.

Comment: I thought that you need to apply `sum` while calculating **@FCost** and **@FBill**. but seems like @Pedram suggestion is also fulfilling here if you don't want to apply sum of values

Comment: Your queries in to `@FBill` and `@FCost` will be returning many rows of data.  Do you mean to get a single value?  If so, do you want an aggregate *(such as the `SUM()` you've previously used)*, or perhaps just 'the first value'?  Alternatively, if you need separate values, do you mean to later `JOIN` on to that set, just like you are doing with other tables?  In short `Please actually describe what you are trying to achieve, and give examples` rather than just copy pasting your code.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the place where you are prone to get error..

```
Set @FBill = (
             Select
                ((dbo.Budget.SalWage * (1 + dbo.Budget.SalWagePerc)) + dbo.budget.PG0 + 
                (dbo.budget.PG * (1 + PGPerc))) / (DAY(EOMONTH(@ToDate))) * Day(@ToDate)

             From dbo.budget 

             WHERE Period >= Month(@FromDate) and Period <= Month(@ToDate)
              )

Set @FCost = (
                Select (dbo.Budget.SalWage + dbo.budget.PG0 + dbo.budget.PG) / 
                (DAY(EOMONTH(@ToDate))) * Day(@ToDate)

                From dbo.budget 

                WHERE Period >= Month(@FromDate) and Period <= Month(@ToDate)
)
```

You can use top and order by to return only one record like below

```
set @fbill=select top 1 from table order by somevalue
```

Comment: Thank You, but I also would like the other values returned. To explain I have sites, Site 1, 2 etc... thus I would like it to do the select per site.

Comment: Then you will need to remove  applying using variables and build the logic using cross apply.Its highly difficult to show you with out some test data

Comment: My apologies, that was not clever of me... haha. This seems to work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try below, Use **Order by** if needed in sub query.

```
Declare @FromDate DateTime
DEclare @ToDate DateTime
Declare @WACost Numeric (18,2)
Declare @WABill Numeric (18,2)
Declare @FBill Numeric (18, 2)
Declare @FCost Numeric (18,2)

Set @FromDate = '20160501'
Set @ToDate = '20160531'

Set @WACost = (Select TOP 1
                    sum(dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + Sum((dbo.FleetData.OwnCost + dbo.FleetData.OpCost)
                    * dbo.DataInput.Hrs)
              From       dbo.DataInput INNER JOIN
                         dbo.HRData ON dbo.DataInput.HRId = dbo.HRData.HRId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetData ON dbo.FleetData.FleetId = dbo.DataInput.FleetId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.WorkCodes ON dbo.DataInput.WorkCodeId = dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID
             WHERE ProdDate >= @FromDate AND ProdDate <= @ToDate and dbo.workcodes.WorkCode = 101
              ) 

Set @WABill = (SELECT TOP 1
                sum(dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + Sum((dbo.FleetData.OwnBill + dbo.FleetData.OpBill)
                * dbo.DataInput.Hrs)
              From dbo.Datainput Inner Join
                   dbo.FleetData ON dbo.FleetData.FleetId = dbo.DataInput.FleetId INNER JOIN
                   dbo.HRData ON dbo.DataInput.HRId = dbo.HRData.HRId INNER JOIN
                   dbo.WorkCodes ON dbo.DataInput.WorkCodeId = dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID
              WHERE ProdDate >= @FromDate AND ProdDate <= @ToDate and dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode = 101
              )

Set @FBill = (SELECT TOP 1 
                ((dbo.Budget.SalWage * (1 + dbo.Budget.SalWagePerc)) + dbo.budget.PG0 + 
                (dbo.budget.PG * (1 + PGPerc))) / (DAY(EOMONTH(@ToDate))) * Day(@ToDate)

             From dbo.budget 

             WHERE Period >= Month(@FromDate) and Period <= Month(@ToDate)
              )

Set @FCost = (SELECT TOP 1 (dbo.Budget.SalWage + dbo.budget.PG0 + dbo.budget.PG) / 
                (DAY(EOMONTH(@ToDate))) * Day(@ToDate)
                From dbo.budget 

                WHERE Period >= Month(@FromDate) and Period <= Month(@ToDate)
             )

SELECT     @WACost as WACostTotal, @WABill as WABillTotal, @FBill as FBillCalc, @FCost as FCostCalc,
                dbo.DataInput.DataInputID as DataInpID, dbo.DataInput.ProdDate as ProdDate, dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode as WCode, dbo.DataInput.Hrs as ProdHrs, dbo.DataInput.Loads as ProdLoads, 
              dbo.DataInput.Fuel as ProdFuel, dbo.FleetData.FleetNo as ProdFltNo, dbo.JobCodes.JobCode, 
              dbo.FleetType.EquipmentType as EqType, dbo.FleetModel.ModelName as Model, dbo.Sites.SiteName as ProdSiteName, 
              dbo.JobCodes.JobDetails as JCDet, dbo.JobCodes.BillMeth as BillM,
              dbo.FleetData.OwnCost as FltOwnCost, dbo.fleetdata.OpCost as FltOpCost, dbo.fleetdata.OwnBill as FltOwnBill,
              dbo.FleetData.OpBill as FltOpBill,

              (dbo.FleetModel.ModelSize * dbo.DataInput.Loads) as ProdBCM,
              dbo.HRData.EmpNo as HREmp, dbo.HRData.RatePH as EmpCost, dbo.HRData.RateBill as EmpBill, 
              dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs as ProdShHrs, dbo.FleetModel.ModelSize as MSize, 
              (dbo.DataInput.Fuel * dbo.JobCodes.FuelRate) as ProdFuelCost,
              dbo.budget.BudDate as BdgDate, dbo.Budget.RevBCM as BdgRevBCM, dbo.Budget.PricePerBCM as BdgBCMPrice,
              dbo.budget.BCMValue as BdgBCMVal, dbo.budget.SalWage as BdgSalWage, dbo.budget.Fuel as FuelBdg, 
              dbo.budget.PG0 as PGZero, dbo.budget.PG as PGCP,
              dbo.budget.siteId as BudgSite,

               --LAST DAY BCM
              IIF(dbo.DataInput.ProdDate = @ToDate, dbo.DataInput.Loads * dbo.FleetModel.ModelSize, 0) as LDBCM,

              --BILLING CALCS

              --PG Billing
              IIF(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.Budget.SalWage * (1 + dbo.Budget.SalWagePerc)) + dbo.budget.PG0 + 
              (dbo.budget.PG * (1 + PGPerc)),0) as PGBill,

              --FleetBill
              IIF(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as FleetBill,

              --LabourCost
              iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill),0) as LabourBill,  

              --Total Variable Bill
              iif(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + 
               (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as TotalVarBill,

               --WABill
               iif(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + 
               (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs) / 
               @WABill * @FBill +
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + 
               (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs), 0) as WABill,

              --COST CALCS

              --PG Cost

              IIF(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.Budget.SalWage + dbo.budget.PG0 + dbo.budget.PG),0) as PGCost,

              --FLEETCOST
              IIF(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as FleetCost,

              --LabourCost
              iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH),0) as LabourCost,

               --Total Variables Cost
               iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as TotalVarCost,

               --WAOnly
               iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs) / 
               @WACost * @FCost,0)
               as WACalc,

               --WA
               iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs) / 
               @WACost * @FCost +
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs) , 0) as WACost


FROM            dbo.DataInput INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetData ON dbo.FleetData.FleetId = dbo.DataInput.FleetId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetMake ON dbo.FleetData.FleetMakeId = dbo.FleetMake.FleetMakeId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetModel ON dbo.FleetData.FleetModelId = dbo.FleetModel.ModelId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetType ON dbo.FleetData.FleetTypeId = dbo.FleetType.FleetTypeId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.HRData ON dbo.DataInput.HRId = dbo.HRData.HRId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Sites ON dbo.DataInput.SiteId = dbo.Sites.SiteId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Budget ON dbo.Sites.SiteId = dbo.Budget.SiteId AND dbo.DataInput.Period = dbo.Budget.Period INNER JOIN
                         dbo.WorkCodes ON dbo.DataInput.WorkCodeId = dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.JobCodes ON dbo.DataInput.JobCodeId = dbo.JobCodes.JobCodeId

WHERE ProdDate >= @FromDate AND ProdDate <= @ToDate

Group By dbo.DataInput.DataInputID, dbo.DataInput.DataInputID, dbo.DataInput.ProdDate, dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode, dbo.DataInput.Hrs,
              dbo.DataInput.Loads, dbo.DataInput.Fuel, dbo.FleetData.FleetNo, dbo.JobCodes.JobCode, 
              dbo.FleetType.EquipmentType, dbo.FleetModel.ModelName, dbo.Sites.SiteName, 
              dbo.JobCodes.JobDetails, dbo.JobCodes.BillMeth, dbo.FleetData.OwnCost, dbo.fleetdata.OpCost, 
              dbo.fleetdata.OwnBill, dbo.FleetData.OpBill,dbo.HRData.EmpNo, dbo.HRData.RatePH, dbo.HRData.RateBill, 
              dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs, dbo.FleetModel.ModelSize, dbo.budget.BudDate, dbo.Budget.RevBCM, dbo.Budget.PricePerBCM,
              dbo.budget.BCMValue, dbo.budget.SalWage, dbo.budget.Fuel, dbo.budget.PG0, dbo.budget.PG,
              dbo.budget.siteId, dbo.jobcodes.FuelRate, dbo.datainput.workcodeid, dbo.budget.SalWagePerc, dbo.Budget.PGPerc, 
              dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID  

Order By dbo.DataInput.ProdDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a notice.

If you want all of May then you should:

```
Set @FromDate = '20160501'
Set @ToDate   = '20160601'
```

and check like:

```
( @FromDate <= ProdDate ) AND ( ProdDate < @ToDate )
```

I think you are missing almost a day.